# Find x-axis value related to maximum value in y-axis ; SPOTFIRE

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to find `x-axis(frequency)` value that corresponds to `max(y-axis)(amplitude)`. 
But it is bit complicated the csv have 3 columns :

```
first - S/N
second - x-axis (frequency)
third - y-axis (amplitude)
```

the graph type is line and the "color by" is S/N column. 
I tried to this IF statement:

```
 If([signal_power [dBm]]]=Max([signal_power [dBm]]]),Max([signal_power [dBm]]]),-1000)
```

the to filter out all the "`-1000`" which will leave me only with the x-axis value that corresponds to the `max(y-axis)`.

the problem is that the IF searches all over the S/N column.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `(Max([signal power]) Over ([S/N]))` instead max only, this will calculate max for each S/N value.

Tip: Instead of `-1000` it's more elegant to use `nul`.